# How to use your custom map for turtlebot navigation in simulation?

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, amcl, transformations

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have built a custom map of my building and I want to use it in simulation (Rviz) to test my code. In simple words, I want some like turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch with my map and without a stage.

I am trying to do it, but I am getting a lot of error. [This](http://answers.ros.org/question/255939/not-able-to-display-robot-model/) is another question I have posted regarding the error I am facing when I launched my custom launch file.

This is my launch file

```
<launch>
<arg name="base"       value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_BASE kobuki)"/>  <!-- create, rhoomba -->
  <arg name="stacks"     value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_STACKS hexagons)"/>  <!-- circles, hexagons -->
  <arg name="3d_sensor"  value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR kinect)"/>  <!-- kinect, asus_xtion_pro -->
  
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/includes/robot.launch.xml">
    <arg name="base" value="$(arg base)" />
    <arg name="stacks" value="$(arg stacks)" />
    <arg name="3d_sensor" value="$(arg 3d_sensor)" />
  </include>
  
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="use_gui" value="true"/>
  </node>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_footprint_to_map" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /base_footprint 100"/>
  
  <node name="rviz1" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find turtlebot_rviz_launchers)/rviz/navigation.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

also I am running a map with `map_server` node and amcl using `rosrun amcl amcl`

In the terminal where I ran amcl node i get an error saying that `no messages revieced on /scan topic`. So, I am not sure how to publish a simulated /scan messages.

Does anyone used a custom map in simulation ( I am sure a lot of people did it). If yes, can you please help me?

Thanks,
Sai Krishna Allani

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256030/how-to-use-your-custom-map-for-turtlebot-navigation-in-simulation?/) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am also doing a similar thing with my irobot create 2 robot.
Were you able to successfully upload your map onto RVIZ( using a .yaml file) ? I am having a similar problem as well.
Please see attached my amcl.launch file for info.
See  [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/257557/using-prebuilt-map-with-amcl-launch-file-how-to-execute-with-rviz/)  for info.
[Screenshot from 2017-03-23 10-48-08.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14902805105021875.png)

---

Originally posted by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) with karma: 96 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0